# javascript function in function runing queue

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am a beginner in javascript. In my react native project I use the react-native-get-sms-android. The first function works. I need to sync two functions. How do I do that?

```
const Sent_SMS = (SMS_Rows) => {
var SetSent = [];
var last = false;
for (let i = 0; i < SMS_Rows.length; i++) {
    
    if(i==SMS_Rows.length-1)
       last=true;

    SmsAndroid.autoSend(
        JSON.stringify(SMS_Rows[i]['phone']),
        SMS_Rows[i]['message'],

        (fail) => {
            //console.log('Failed with this error: ' + fail);
        },
        (success) => {
            //console.log('SMS sent successfully');
            SetSent.push(SMS_Rows[i]['id']);
            if (last==true) {
                console.log(SetSent);
            }
        },

    );
}
```

}

my output is true,true,true,true

Comment: It's *JavaScript*, not *Java*. Java is a completely different language.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: *"my output is true,true,true,true"* I don't see how it can be, unless you've left off the part showing that those values are in an array, and `SMS_Rows[i]['id']` is always the value `true`.

Comment: my array have 6 object i need when for in the last index last=true and log the setsent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the logic inside for loop to a separate function.

```
function sendSMS(SMS_Rows, i){
  SmsAndroid.autoSend(
        JSON.stringify(SMS_Rows[i]['phone']),
        SMS_Rows[i]['message'],

        (fail) => {
            //console.log('Failed with this error: ' + fail);
        },
        (success) => {
            //console.log('SMS sent successfully');
            SetSent.push(SMS_Rows[i]['id']);
            if (i == SMS_Rows.length - 1) {
                console.log(SetSent);
            }
        },

    );
}
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sendSMS(SMS_Rows, i);
}
```

Tested. The `console.log` will get fired after the last SMS message. Let know if it works.